# Are 2 rare events that happen simultaneously likely dependent?

Tags: probability

Assuming there are two extremely rare events in a given time period A and B, and given both events have happened in the same time period, can this be an indication that these two events are likely not independent?

Intuitively, if these are the only two events, then certainly, `P(A)P(B) < P(A)P(B|A)`. However, if there are more events, C,D,E etc, then it seems pretty likely that at least two of them will happen simultaneously.

I am being curious due to a real life situation I encountered. After running a nightly test suite on a software I am working on, two rare problems, never seen before, appeared. So we had a discussion with one of my colleagues, on whether it is wise to assume the two are related, or it can be coincidence.

So can someone please clarify this, also is it applicable to real life situations like the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, each with positive probability. Can they be independent? No. This follows since $P(A)P(B) \gt0$ yet $P(AB)=P(\emptyset)=0$.

So, if $P(AB)=0$, then $P(A|B) = P(B|A) = 0$. Thus, you might ask yourself if once you've lived a rare event $A$ or $B$, then, after a period of time, rare events $B$ or $A$ can occur, respectively. This is, ¿Are $P(A|B) = P(B|A) = 0$? If the anser is yes, then them both are dependent.

However, it can't be assumed they are independent otherwise.

Comment: So basically you are saying one result is not enough to say anything?

Comment: If you solve rare problem A and then rare problem B disappears, them both are dependent. How ever, If after solving problem A and then B partially deacreases, thus only a part of B is dependent of A.